# How to merge rows if the column value is None with no aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

If I have the following data frame in python

```
   Date    |    Item    |    B1      |    B1 Quantity   |    B2       |  B2 Quantity 
2-18-2019  |    NY01    |    dNo     |       efa        |     None    |   None 
2-18-2019  |    NY01    |   1dfs     |       e3f3       |     None    |   None         
2-18-2019  |    NY01    |    None    |       None       |     85      |   q2d  
2-19-2019  |    Du02    |    dfgwe   |        eef       |     None    |   None        
2-19-2019  |    Du01    |    None    |       None       |     ddd     |   fve3
2-20-2019  |    Ps55    |     df     |       fdr        |     None    |   None          
2-20-2019  |    Ps55    |     None   |       None       |     6edc    |   ewc
2-20-2019  |    Du85    |    hiid    |       41fe18     |     None    |   None           
2-20-2019  |    Du85    |    fvcv    |       fe3v       |     None    |   None           
2-20-2019  |    Du85    |    None    |       None       |     Neww    |   Newe           
2-20-2019  |    Du85    |    None    |       None       |     dfi     |    dc
```

and I want to merge the rows where Date == Date and Item == Item and and there is a values for the empty cell in the row below it if there is no value then the row should be the same
so the result should look like the table below

```
   Date    |    Item    |    B1      |    B1 Quantity   |    B2     |  B2 Quantity 
2-18-2019  |    NY01    |    dNo     |       efa        |    None   |   None 
2-18-2019  |    NY01    |   1dfs     |       e3f3       |    85     |   q2d         
2-19-2019  |    Du02    |    dfgwe   |        eef       |    ddd    |   fve3
2-20-2019  |    Ps55    |     df     |       fdr        |    6edc   |   ewc          
2-20-2019  |    Du85    |    hiid    |       41fe18     |    Neww   |   Newe           
2-20-2019  |    Du85    |    fvcv    |       fe3v       |    dfi    |   dc
```

Comment: How many columns like B1... B2... do you have?

Comment: only two :B1 and B2 @Corralien

Comment: Can you check your output please? Why Du01 and Du02 was merged?

Comment: the logic is bisaclly if date == date and item==item then we should fill None in row one with the data in row2 so Dou85 we has four of them filled the None in first two rows with values in B2 in the last two rows

Comment: You merged Item Du02 and Du01 together.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially I want to shift the index according to the amount of nulls in `B1` and the re-join to the original dataframe with the shifted index. Assuming your base dataframe is called `df_1`, then this solves your issue:

```
aux = df_1[df_1['B1'].isna()].reset_index().merge((df_1[df_1['B1'].isna()].groupby(['Date','Item'],as_index=False).agg(aux = pd.NamedAgg('B2','count'))))[['index','aux','B2','B2 Quantity']]
aux['join_index'] = aux['index'] - aux['aux']
```

Here I have subsetted the values that will be replacing the Nulls in the original dataframe, but because they have different indexes, I'm calculating the index they should be joined to as "index of the null values - amount of nulls in that subgroup (Date and Item)". Next step, join back to the original dataframe:

```
output = df_1.dropna(subset='B1').drop(columns=['B2','B2 Quantity']).merge(aux,
                                        how='left',
                                        left_index=True,
                                        right_on='join_index').drop(columns=['new_index','index','aux']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Returning:

```
        Date  Item     B1 B1 Quantity    B2 B2 Quantity
0  2-18-2019  NY01    dNo         efa   NaN         NaN
1  2-18-2019  NY01   1dfs        e3f3    85         q2d
2  2-19-2019  Du02  dfgwe         eef   ddd        fve3
3  2-20-2019  Ps55     df         fdr  6edc         ewc
4  2-20-2019  Du85   hiid      41fe18  Neww        Newe
5  2-20-2019  Du85   fvcv        fe3v   dfi          dc
```

Comment: it doesn't work its returning the same output

Comment: How is it returning the same output? I just ran the code and it generated my output which matches your expected output...? Are you sure you are doing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified your dataframe (I changed Du01 to Du02, see below):

```
cols = ['Date', 'Item']
b1 = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('B1')].tolist()
b2 = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('B2')].tolist()

def merge(df):
    mask = df['B1'].isna()
    df1 = df.loc[~mask, cols+b1]
    df2 = df.shift(-mask.sum()).dropna(subset='B2')[b2]
    return pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
    
out = df.groupby(['Date', 'Item'], sort=False, as_index=False).apply(merge).droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
        Date  Item     B1 B1 Quantity    B2 B2 Quantity
0  2-18-2019  NY01    dNo         efa   NaN         NaN
1  2-18-2019  NY01   1dfs        e3f3    85         q2d
3  2-19-2019  Du02  dfgwe         eef   ddd        fve3
5  2-20-2019  Ps55     df         fdr  6edc         ewc
7  2-20-2019  Du85   hiid      41fe18  Neww        Newe
8  2-20-2019  Du85   fvcv        fe3v   dfi          dc
```

Problem for Du02 and Du01:

```
# Input
   Date    |    Item    |    B1      |    B1 Quantity   |    B2     |  B2 Quantity 
2-19-2019  |    Du02    |    dfgwe   |        eef       |     None    |   None        
2-19-2019  |    Du01    |    None    |       None       |     ddd     |   fve3

# Output
   Date    |    Item    |    B1      |    B1 Quantity   |    B2     |  B2 Quantity 
2-19-2019  |    Du02    |    dfgwe   |        eef       |    ddd    |   fve3
```

It's not possible because Du02 != Du01.